# [iOS][objC] unable to convert value in NSDictionary to NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I intend to convert the NSDictionary* object in iOS SDK to NSString*.

Lets say my NSDictionary object has following key value pairs:
{"aps":{"badge":9, "alert":"hello"}} (notice that value itself is a NSDictionary object)
and I want it to convert into a hash map with key value pair as {"aps":"badge:9, alert:hello"} (notice value is just a string).

I am able to print the value in NsDictionary using the following code:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo; //it is passed as an argument and contains the string I mentioned above
for (id key in userInfo)
{
     NSString* value = [userInfo valueForKey:key]; 
     funct( [value UTF9String]; // my function 
}
```

But i am not able to call any NSString method on value object like UTT8String. It gives me error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException: reason [_NSCFDictionary UTF8String]: unrecognised selector sent to instance

Comment: It gives me error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException: reason [_NSCFDictionary UTF8String]: unrecognised selector sent to instance

Comment: Sounds like it's a nested dictionary

Comment: Why are you trying to go from a NSDictionary to a HashMap?

Comment: @danielbeard is right... It looks like it's nested.

Comment: you can try [value UTF8String];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way out. calling the description method on the NSDictionary object gives me what I needed exactly. Stupid to have missed it on first go.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to recursively process the dictionary structure, here is an example that you should be able to adapt:

```
-(void)processParsedObject:(id)object{
   [self processParsedObject:object depth:0 parent:nil];
}

-(void)processParsedObject:(id)object depth:(int)depth parent:(id)parent{

   if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){

      for(NSString * key in [object allKeys]){
         id child = [object objectForKey:key];
         [self processParsedObject:child depth:depth+1 parent:object];
      }                         


   }else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){

      for(id child in object){
         [self processParsedObject:child depth:depth+1 parent:object];
      }   

   }
   else{
      //This object is not a container you might be interested in it's value
      NSLog(@"Node: %@  depth: %d",[object description],depth);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply that loop to each child, not the main dictionary.  You said yourself you have a dictionary in a dictionary:

```
for(id key in userInfo)
{
    NSDictionary *subDict = [userInfo valueForKey:key];
    for(id subKey in subDict)
    {
        NSString* value = [subDict valueForKey:subKey]; 
    }
}
```

This loop assumes you have the entire dictionary in the first level, otherwise you will need to use danielbeard's recursive method.